# What folder does cyanogenmod store its updates?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing

I reverted to an older version of Cyanongenmod today. Now my phone reboots continuously. I want to try flashing on of the images that cyanogenmod downloaded in the past. What folder are they stored in?

Comment: Did you wipe the data partition when you installed the new image? You need to do that when changing major versions.

Comment: It was a step downgrade. What does that remove? My passwords? Wifi keys?

Comment: Accounts, apps, settings, etc. Pretty much anything that was not on your phone when you first unboxed it, except the operating system itself and (usually) media files. The [tag wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) has a pretty good explanation. Also, based on the [CMUpdater source](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_CMUpdater), it looks like the update packages should be in `/sdcard/cmupdater`, but I cannot verify this myself (don't have CM).

Answer (score 15):

You can find it under:

```
/storage/emulated/0/cmupdater
```

Comment: Why not Downloads? =D

Answer (score 5):

On LineageOS (the new Cyanogenmod in 2017) it is in `/data/data/org.lineageos.updater/app_updates/`

Comment: I wonder why doesn’t it show up in Apps? There seems to be no usable way to clean it up.

Comment: No clue. I just know my phone was stuck at boot until i could find the file.
Fortunately applying this file for the update made it boot again.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Google Apps addon (gapps) and are updating between versions where your ... You will find downloaded zip under /sdcard/cmupdater directory.